# Barrel cannon don't appear in Fungi Forest

Tags: nintendo-64, donkey-kong-64

I'm playing Donkey Kong 64 on Nintendo 64, and when I get to the giant mushroom on the red tunnel, I shot the 5 switches on the wall with each Kong, but the cannon didn't appear, so I'm not able to take the golden banana of the Donkey Kong pad.

I've already tried restarting the console.

I'm not trying to end the game with 100%, so there is no problem if I can't get it, but is there anything I can do?